# how to compress image size to 5MB in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I am working with an APIs which is throwing error when image is greater than 5MB. Now I want to compress the size of image if image size is greater than 5MB then it should compress that to 5MB. Is there any way to do that other than mentioned method
`ImagePicker.pickImage(source: picker.ImageSource.gallery,imageQuality: 50)`

or how exactly `imageQuality` works If you know the exact behavior then please mention that also.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try this https://pub.dev/documentation/image_picker/latest/image_picker/ImagePicker/pickImage.html

Answer (score 2):

The imageQuality argument modifies the quality of the image, ranging from 0-100 where 100 is the original/max quality. If imageQuality is null, the image with the original quality will be returned. Compression is only supported for certain image types such as JPEG and on Android PNG and WebP, too. If compression is not supported for the image that is picked, a warning message will be logged.

https://pub.dev/documentation/image_picker/latest/image_picker/ImagePicker/pickImage.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flutter_image_compress dependency.

Look this example:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress

Comment: Is this work for all formats of Images?

Answer (score 1):

As of my solution try to use SVG image instead of jpg or png it may help you to reduce size.
If You don't find solution then ping me we will try to solve the issue.
SVG is highest quality images because it draw by pixels to pixels.

Comment: i need to know you question is solved or not

Comment: Any random raster image should not be converted to SVG, it will drastically increase the image size and performs horribly when rendered. I assume the question is asking for any general image so your answer of using SVG is not helpful here.

Comment: but as your designer design the app from there you can take svg images and make your app more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for the [pickImage method](https://pub.dev/documentation/image_picker/latest/image_picker/ImagePicker/pickImage.html).

> If specified, the image will be at most `maxWidth` wide and `maxHeight` tall. Otherwise, the image will be returned at its original width and height. The `imageQuality` argument modifies the quality of the image, ranging from 0-100 where 100 is the original/max quality. If `imageQuality` is null, the image with the original quality will be returned. Compression is only supported for certain image types such as JPEG and on Android PNG and WebP, too. If compression is not supported for the image that is picked, a warning message will be logged.